# itextsharp pdfpcell header

Tags: c#, java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I'd like to have a table of cells of class PdfPCell each with a tiny header, main string and tiny footer. I can't find a way to insert them since HeaderandFooter is not allowed element to add to the cell, one paragraph overwrites another and so on. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use nested tables.
Instead of a PdfPCell, insert a 1x1 table with a tiny header & a tiny footer.

**EDIT:**

let's forget about table footer and header feature of iTextSharp because it's useful when a table spans over multiple pages and then you have footer & header repeated. In our case, header & footer will belong to the inner table that will contain only 3 cells, so let's use PdfPCell for all of them.

Then main function is `GetHFCell` that will return a PdfPTable containing a customized header cell (height, font, text,..), a customized footer cell & a middle cell containing the main text.
This function is called whenever we want to add a cell to our main table (example of how to use this function in `GeneratePDF`).

```
    private static PdfPTable GetHFCell(string header, string footer, string text)
    {
        PdfPTable pdft;
        PdfPCell hc;
        PdfPCell fc;

        pdft = new PdfPTable(1);
        pdft.WidthPercentage = 100f;
        pdft.DefaultCell.Border = 0;

        hc = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(header));
        hc.Top = 0f;
        hc.FixedHeight = 7f;
        hc.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        hc.BackgroundColor = iTextSharp.text.Color.ORANGE;
        ((Chunk)(hc.Phrase[0])).Font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(((Chunk)(hc.Phrase[0])).Font.Family, 5f);

        fc = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(footer));
        hc.Top = 0f;
        fc.FixedHeight = 7f;
        hc.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        fc.BackgroundColor = iTextSharp.text.Color.YELLOW;
        ((Chunk)(fc.Phrase[0])).Font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(((Chunk)(fc.Phrase[0])).Font.Family, 5f);

        pdft.AddCell(hc);
        pdft.AddCell(text);
        pdft.AddCell(fc);

        return pdft;
    }

    public void GeneratePDF()
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        try
        {            
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("File1.pdf", FileMode.Create));

            document.Open();

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
            table.DefaultCell.Padding = 0;
            table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 2f;
            for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    //calling GetHFCell
                    table.AddCell(
                        GetHFCell("header " + ((int)(i + 5 * (j - 1))).ToString(), 
                                  "footer " + ((int)(i + 5 * (j - 1))).ToString(), 
                                  "z" + j.ToString() + i.ToString()));
                }
            }

            document.Add(table);
        }
        catch (DocumentException de)
        {
            //...
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            //...
        }
        document.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do, but so far unsuccessfully. Could you please be a little more specific? I tried to create a new PdfPTable with 1 column. I set 1 row for header and 1 for footer. However, I am not able to force them into that table.

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!